# Kafka Connect Jdbc sink with protobuf convertor - How to use null values?

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-connect

As title says i have a protobuff definition that imports
*"google/protobuf/wrappers.proto"*.

When im trying to push into mysql via kafka jdbc connector im getting the error

> Unsupported source data type: STRUCT.

But i dont have any structs.

In the [confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-protobuf.html#handling-null-values-with-wrappers) the nullable options is mentions, but i cant figure out where I need to enable it.

This is my protobuff and connector settings

```
    {
      "transforms": "TimestampConverter,RenameField",
      "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
      "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'\''T'\''HH:mm:ss",
      "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp",
      "transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "timestampUtc,timestampLocal",

      "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
      "transforms.RenameField.renames": "Id:MonitoringEventId,TimestampUtc:Date,EventType:Type,DeviceType:GeneratedBy",
      "transforms.RenameField.blacklist": "Duration,TypeId,TimestampLocal",

      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
    }
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message MonitoringEventDAO {
    uint64 Id = 1;
    string TimestampUtc = 2;
    string TimestampLocal = 3;
    uint32 Duration = 4;

    uint32 BaseStationId = 5;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value CameraId = 6;
    uint32 AccountId = 7;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value SubjectId = 8;

    uint32 DeviceType = 9;
    uint32 TypeId = 10;
    string Message = 11;

    string Version = 12;
    uint32 EventType = 13;
    string Hash = 14;

    google.protobuf.StringValue StorageUrl = 15;
    bool PresentationUploaded = 16;
    uint32 DataType = 17;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value Frames = 18;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value Fps = 19;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value SampleRate = 20;
}
```

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
  `MonitoringEventId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BaseStationId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `CameraId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubjectId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `GeneratedBy` int NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `Message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `Hash` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `Version` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `Type` int NOT NULL,
  `ReviewMonitoringEventReviewId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `BreathingDataUrl` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `VideoUrl` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `DataType` int NOT NULL,
  `StorageUrl` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `Uploaded` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PresentationStorageUrl` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `PresentationUploaded` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Frames` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fps` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SampleRate` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MonitoringEventId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_AccountId` (`AccountId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_BaseStationId` (`BaseStationId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_CameraId` (`CameraId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_Date` (`Date`),
  KEY `IX_Events_GeneratedBy` (`GeneratedBy`),
  KEY `IX_Events_Hash` (`Hash`),
  KEY `IX_Events_ReviewMonitoringEventReviewId` (`ReviewMonitoringEventReviewId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_SubjectId` (`SubjectId`),
  KEY `IX_Events_Type` (`Type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_Accounts_AccountId` FOREIGN KEY (`AccountId`) REFERENCES `Accounts` (`AccountId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_BaseStations_BaseStationId` FOREIGN KEY (`BaseStationId`) REFERENCES `BaseStations` (`BaseStationId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_Cameras_CameraId` FOREIGN KEY (`CameraId`) REFERENCES `Cameras` (`CameraId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_MonitoringEventReview_ReviewMonitoringEventReviewId` FOREIGN KEY (`ReviewMonitoringEventReviewId`) REFERENCES `MonitoringEventReview` (`MonitoringEventReviewId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_Subjects_SubjectId` FOREIGN KEY (`SubjectId`) REFERENCES `Subjects` (`SubjectId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:591)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unsupported source data type: STRUCT
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.bindField(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1578)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialect.bindField(DatabaseDialect.java:608)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindField(PreparedStatementBinder.java:186)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindNonKeyFields(PreparedStatementBinder.java:172)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindRecord(PreparedStatementBinder.java:103)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:184)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:79)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:563)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: a field can be null or not, according to schema. can you post your schema?

Comment: My database scheme ? I have added it now

Comment: Oh I was talking about the schema in schema registry, since you have `"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"` line in your configuration. you should have something like http://localhost:8081/subjects/your_schema-value

Comment: I have added it, it is the protobuf file

Comment: Can you please show more of the stacktrace? You do have Structs - the whole value is one. Also, what is your key converter set to?

Comment: I have added the exception, I do not have any key convertor set becausethere is not key in the message. The STRUCT Exception accured only where there are nullable fields, when I Ignore thos tields, the message is accepted and the connector works.